# GAS CODE FOR API

Tags: google-apps-script

I got a task to write a GAS (Google app script) that can fetch the uv(unique visitor) of any website from API compete.com . I had hard coded the domain in my link.But It is required that it should work for any domain user wants. I am a beginner , Please help me regarding this. Here is what i did :

```
function fetch() {    
    var url = 'https://apps.compete.com/sites/abcdef.com/trended/search/?apikey=myapikey&metrics=uv'; 

    var response= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);// Recieves the response corresponding to above request.

    Logger.log('\n\nThe number of unique visitors correponding to months is : \n\n'+response);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question here stands for how can you ask first for user input, end then run your function?

This can be done in many ways, but I will give you the UiApp option:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var chooseURLLabel = app.createLabel("Input a URL");
  var URLValue = app.createTextBox().setId("idURL").setName("idURL");
  var visitHandler = app.createServerHandler('getVisitorsFunction').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var getVisitors = app.createButton("Get visitors").addClickHandler(visitHandler);
  panel
  .add(chooseURLLabel)
  .add(URLValue)
  .add(getVisitors);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
function getVisitorsFunction(e){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var visitors = fetch(e.parameter.idURL);
app.add(app.createLabel(visitors));
return app
}
function fetch(url) {    
    var response= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

    return "The number of unique visitors correponding to months is : "+response
}
```

Comment: Sir, when i am running the function doGet(), I cant see the horizontal panel over there in spreadsheet? can you please tell me what to do next?

Comment: So you want the input from spreadsheet? Then it's a little bit easier. First, make sure the script is bound to that spreadsheet. You can check this by opening your spreadsheet, clicking tools and then script editor - if you see this script there, then you can move forward. As you can see, fetch function takes as input URL, which means that you can go to your spreadsheet, type `=fetch(b1)` or any other cell, and in that cell paste the url. It will retrieve your values.